# Possible to draw css border around icon font that is a circle shape?

Tags: html, css, svg, icon-fonts

I am using icomoon for my icon fonts. Some icons are circular in shape. Is there a way that I can draw a circular border around the icon shape?

I've tried targeting the icon and adding a border to it, but it draws as a box border. Is there a way I can target the shape itself?

HTML

`<span class="icn icn-clock-circle" style="border: 1px solid red;">::before</span>`

CSS

`.icn-clock-circle:before {content: "\e9dd";}`

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, put a `border-radius` on your `::before` element:

```
.icn-clock-circle::before {
    content: "\e9dd";
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: red solid 1px;
}
```

You will have to adjust the `width` and `height` values to the size of the icon, as you didn't provide enough HTML/CSS.

Comment: Beat me to it! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can curve borders by using `border-radius`. For a circle, I would typically use `border-radius: 50%;`

Read more about how to curve different corners on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)